# MongoDB update, delete document from array

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection like this:

```
db.users.findOne({'_id':ObjectId("541a8cac7f8b9acf408b4567")});
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("541a8cac7f8b9acf408b4567"),
    "friends" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("541adb1f7f8b9ad0408b4567"),
            "time" : 1411046195
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("541adb1f7f8b9ad0408b5467"),
            "time" : 1411046123
        }
    ]
}
```

and I use this to delete:

```
db.users.update({'uuid':'wb_2204553113'}, {'$pullAll':{friends:[{_id:ObjectId('541adb1f7f8b9ad0408b4567'), time:{$gt:0}}] } } );
```

but is return null , it's confused！

Comment: What do u want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unlike the $pull operator that removes elements by specifying a query, $pullAll removes elements that match the listed values.

So your update in that case should be:

`db.users.update(
{'uuid' : 'wb_2204553113'}, 
{$pullAll : 
    {friends:  [{_id : ObjectId('541adb1f7f8b9ad0408b4567') , time : 1411046195}]}
}
);`

Note the exact time value.

You can express the above with `$pull` of course:

`db.users.update(
{'uuid' : 'wb_2204553113'}, 
{$pull : {friends: {_id : ObjectId('541adb1f7f8b9ad0408b4567') , time : {$gt : 0}}}}
);`

Which in your case can be expressed also as:

`db.users.update(
{'uuid' : 'wb_2204553113'}, 
{$pull : {friends: {_id : ObjectId('541adb1f7f8b9ad0408b4567')}}}
);`

`